# Print double with exact length in java

Tags: java, format

I could not find answer for my question on the net, so that's why I'm here.

I want to print a number with specified number of digits example in java:

```
Length = 10

1.123456789      ==> 1.123456789

123.123456789    ==> 123.1234567

123456.123456789 ==> 123456.1234
```

Comment: What about `12345678911` (an eleven-digit number)?

Comment: I'm trying different format methods, but nothing works so far, and yes i need a number with exact number of digits .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save the number as string and take the substring from 0 to 10. now you can parse it back and got the number with 10 digits

Answer (score 3):

It seems you need to fetch the first `n` digits from the `String` representation of the number. However, the decimal separator should not be counted as a digit:

```
String printNumber(double number, int n) {
   String value = String.valueOf(number);
   String result = "";
   int count = 0;
   for (char c : value.toCharArray()) {
       if (count == n) break;
       if (c != '.') {
           count++;
       }
       result += c;
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: only need to check if there is a decimal part here, the separator is not count ;)

Comment: 100.1 wont work for n==4

Comment: @xro7, true. Will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Double number = 1.123456789;
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(number).setScale(6, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
System.out.println("double value: " + bigDecimal.doubleValue());
```

In the `setScale` method you can choose number of digits after dot.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can calculate the amount based on the length of the non-decimal number:

```
public String doubleToString(double in) {
    int length = (((int) in) + "").length(); //non-decimal length
    if (length <= 0 || length > 10) {
        //error out? not sure how you wish to handle 11-digit numbers
    }
    return String.format("%." + (10 - length) + "f", in); //format decimal
}
```

Shortened:

```
//default to 0 decimals for >10 digits
public String doubleToString(double in) {
    return String.format("%." + Math.max(0, (10 - (((int) in) + "").length()) + "f", in);
}
```